# I am using ,maven for the first time, it is failing to build by showing some compiler error

Tags: maven

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\madhav\cluster_projects\firstmaven\target\classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
      C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar
    Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
    not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
    In most cases you can change the location of your Java
    installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
    [INFO] 1 error
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.314 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-02T05:32:33-07:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/113M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project firstmaven: Compilation failure
    [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
    [ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\..\lib\tools.jar
    [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
    [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
    [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
    [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] `enter code here`
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Hi,

I am using java 8, 64 bit and apache maven3.3.9.
 I am getting this error message while running maven clean install, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: JAVA_HOME  is set to a JRE not to the JDK

Answer (score 0):

Have you set java home properly ??

see this link to know how to set  https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

you can check if the java home is set by typing java in console if properly set it will list the options

Comment: Yes I have set the JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME Path correctly.

Comment: "Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
    not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required)."

Comment: I am using jdk 1.8

Comment: you need JDK not JRE . that means the JAVA_HOME will be like  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74

Comment: Yes, its same as you told(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74)

Comment: type mvn -version and reply what you get

Comment: C:\Users\RMadhav>mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifie
dException

C:\Users\RMadhav

Comment: Something like this I am getting

Comment: [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid li
fecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id
>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are
: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, p
rocess-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-
sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-
test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-